# code stops working when server sends error status

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I am new to rxjs Observables. I am trying simple login page application. When I am sending correct credentials, code is working fine and loading spinner also stops rendering. When credentials are invalid then code stops working and spinner also stays on the page. I have to reload the page to make it work again.
Here's the code :

```
import constants from "../constants";
import "rxjs";
import { ajax } from "rxjs/observable/dom/ajax";
import { loginBody } from "../utils/bodyCreator";
import {
  showLoadingSpinner,
  hideLoadingSpinner
} from "../actions/LoadingOverlayActions";

const sessionCreated = payload => ({
  type: constants.sessionCreated,
  response: payload
});

export const tryLoginEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(constants.tryLogin)
    .map(() => store.dispatch(showLoadingSpinner()))
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax
        .post(constants.loginEndPoint, loginBody(store.getState()), {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        })
        .map(data => store.dispatch(sessionCreated(data.response)))
        .map(() => store.dispatch(hideLoadingSpinner()))
        .catch(err => store.dispatch(hideLoadingSpinner()))
    );
```

Please help me how to do this and what is wrong in this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.catch` operator in a different way. For example, return empty Observable (or other action), something like:

```js
.catch(error => {
  store.dispatch(hideLoadingSpinner());
  return Observable.empty();
})
```

see official documentation on [catchError operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/function/index.html#static-function-catchError)